# LDA for Html Documents in Genism

Tags: python, gensim

I have bunch of html documents 10-15 on which i have to apply LDA algorithm in gensim
I am stuck on creating the corpus as i don't understand how i design a corpus for a collection of html documents. The example on the site shows the creation of them on wikipedia compressed file .xml.bz

Anyone please guide me how can i apply LDA on bunch of html documents.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out HTML processing libraries, like `lxml` or `beautifulsoup`.

For higher level processing (removal of boilerplate, extracting plain text from HTML), have a look at e.g. Honza Pomikalek's [jusText](https://github.com/miso-belica/jusText) package.

Once you have plain text documents, you can proceed as per [gensim's tutorials](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html).